# Summation over an index and a set

Tags: summation, sets, indexed-variable

[image]

I have an index `CC` and a set of values `CM`, and `c is an element of CM` and `CM` is a subset of `CC`. I have two summations shown above. The first summation is over index `CC` and the subset `CM`. The light brown colored part of the first summation is telling that the summation should include only if `c` is an element of `CM`. The second summation is over the elements of `CM`.

These two summations appear in an equation (not given here for simplicity). Is there an easy way to perform these summations?

Thank you...

**EDIT 1**
The answer to the above summations is as follows.

```
(* first summation *)

tq[1]*PD[1]+
tq[2]*PD[2]+PM[2] +
tq[3]*PD[3]+PM[3] +
tq[4]*PD[4]+
tq[5]*PD[5]+
tq[6]*PD[6]+PM[6]+
tq[7]*PD[7]

(* Second summation *)

tq[2]*(PD[2]+QD[2])+
tq[3]*(PD[3]+QD[3])+
tq[6]*(PD[6]+QD[6])
```

Comment: Is your first sum = `tq[1]*PD[1]+ tq[2]*PD[2]+PM[2]+ tq[3]*PD[3]+PM[3]+ tq[4]*PD[4]+ tq[5]*PD[5]+ tq[6]*PD[6]+PM[6]+ tq[7]*PD[7]`? Is your second sum = `tq[2]*PD[2]*QD[2]+ tq[3]*PD[3]*QD[3]+ tq[6]*PD[6]*QD[6]`?

Comment: @Bill: Yes, your answer is right. I edited the question with the expected answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is desirable to have everything in a single sum, then the first sum could be written as

```
cc = 7;
CM = {2, 3, 6};
Sum[tq[c]*PD[c] + PM[c] Boole[MemberQ[CM, c]], {c, cc}]
(* PM[2] + PM[3] + PM[6] + PD[1] tq[1] + PD[2] tq[2] + PD[3] tq[3] + 
   PD[4] tq[4] + PD[5] tq[5] + PD[6] tq[6] + PD[7] tq[7] *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed because you helped me solve another question for which I was preparing a `MM` example. Tugrul

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
Sum[tq[c] PD[c], {c, 7}] + Sum[PM[c], {c, CM}]
(* PM[2] + PM[3] + PM[6] + PD[1] tq[1] + PD[2] tq[2] + PD[3] tq[3] + 
   PD[4] tq[4] + PD[5] tq[5] + PD[6] tq[6] + PD[7] tq[7] *)

Sum[tq[c] pd[c] qd[c], {c, CM}]
(* pd[2] qd[2] tq[2] + pd[3] qd[3] tq[3] + pd[6] qd[6] tq[6] *)
```

If desired, `Sum[tq[c] PD[c], {c, 7}]` can be replaced by `Sum[tq[c] PD[c], {c, CC}]`, yielding the same result.